# How to build a regex w/ new RegExp()

Tags: javascript, regex

Have an array of local storage keys that looks something like this

```
[
  '$gl-user',
  '$gl-date-preference::22'
  '$gl-date-preference::28'
  '$gl-mg-filters::22::1'
  '$gl-mg-filters::22::8'
]
```

- First `::_number_` represents the `storeId`.
- Second `::_number_` can
  represents any additional identifier.

Trying to build a function that takes a `storeId` and returns all keys that match that `storeId`. So if `22` was passed in to that function it would return

```
[
  '$gl-date-preference::22',
  '$gl-mg-filters::22::1',
  '$gl-mg-filters::22::8'
]
```

Here is my first attempt. Copying this into the console returns null every time but I do not understand why.

```
var regex = new RegExp('^[$\w\d\-]+\:\:' + '22');
'$gl-mg-filters::22'.match(regex);
```

Any assistance in getting this regex to work, or ideas on a better solution would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex isn't matching, because you're only escaping with the slashes inside of the string. Instead, you should be escaping it twice, e.g.:

```
var regex = new RegExp('^[$\\w\\d\\-]+\\:\\:' + '22');
'$gl-mg-filters::22'.match(regex);
```

Your initial attempt would try to compile `^[$wd-]+::22` into a Regex.